# How to loop over a queryset for instantiate all formset?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-queryset, formset

I wish I could make a loop that would allow me to instantiate all my formsets for now I have written

```
def access(request, page_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':  
            formset = ReplyFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, initial=[{'instance':instance,}])
    if formset.is_valid():
        #...
        return ...
    else:
        formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.filter(question=questions))
        return ...
```

On this last line that I recovered the information in the db but just for my first forms! Is there way to make a loop so that it instantiates me all the forms?

I tried something like this but it does not work :

```
else:
    for form in formset:
    form.formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.filter(question=questions))
return ...
```

This line only works for my first form :

```
formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.filter(question=questions))
```

**How can I do to affect it at all?**

Should I change my **init** function of my ReplyForm ?

Comment: What is `questions`, a list?

Comment: `questions = Question.objects.filter(page=page_id)`

Comment: You could try: `formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.filter(question__in=questions))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
formset = ReplyFormSet(queryset=Reply.objects.filter(question__in=questions))
```

Using the [`in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in) filter you get every `question` which is in `questions` queryset.